# When does Azure DevOps freeze variable values?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I was looking for documentation on when Azure DevOps 'freezes' the variable values for pipelines. This is mainly important when updating variables, either pipeline variables or within variable groups. As far as I know, DevOps creates a copy of the variable at some point so that if you redeploy a pipeline or change a variable in the meantime, you do not get the updated value for existing releases. But I'm not sure at which point in time that variable values are frozen, nor whether this behavior is equal for variables defined in the pipeline (for the entire release or for a specific stage) and variable groups.

If anyone could either point out the relevant documentation (which I was not able to find myself) or give me some insights into how this works, that would be great!

Comment: Take a look @ https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch 

Azure Pipelines supports three different ways to reference variables: macro, template expression, and runtime expression. 

template expression -> compile time, before runtime starts. 
macro syntax variables -> during runtime before a task runs. 
runtime expressions -> during runtime but were designed for use with conditions and expressions.

Comment: @GeralexGR thanks, helps but does not answer my question about the variables (from outside the pipeline) being frozen.